# Cant get the JSON output to loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, local-storage

I want to loop true certain elements, in this case all with the class "widget", and get there id and title(later on more stuff), store it as JSON in the localStorage(must be a string so we stringify the data), get the data from the localStorage and loop the results. All goes well until i want to loop it(JSON output is valid), this wont work, and i have been working on it for more than a day now so i hope that anybody see what i am doing wrong.

(yes i have looked on the web)

I am still a noob at this so if there are better ways to store and loop this let me know.

// html

```
<div class="widget" id="w1">
   <h2>some text</h2>
</div>

...
...
...
```

// setting the data

```
var storeStr = '';
    storeStr += '{"widget":[';
$('.widget').each(function(){                   
    storeStr += '{';                                
    storeStr += '"id": "'+$(this).attr('id')+'",';
    storeStr += '"title": "'+$(this).children('h2').text()+'"';
    storeStr += '},';
});
storeStr += ']}';
var storeStr = storeStr.replace(/\},]/g,'}]');// comma cleanup
localStorage.setItem('thelskey', storeStr);
```

// output(json valid)

```
{ 
  "widget":[
     {"id": "w1","title": "xxxxx"},
     {"id": "w2","title": "xxxxx"},
     {"id": "w3","title": "xxxxx"},
     {"id": "w4","title": "xxxxx"}
  ]
}
```

// the loop

```
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('thelskey'));

for(var key in json){
    //output
}
```

Comment: yes i get the xxx is undefined (example json[0].widget.id > json[0].widget is undefined) and its always the same undefined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON object only has a single *key*, `"widget"`. So there's no point in looping through it. If you want to get all of the widget data, you need to loop through each item under the `widget` property, i.e.

```
for (var key in json.widget) {
  // output
}
```

Otherwise, don't wrap the array in the extra object, and just construct your JSON as:

```
[
  {"id": "w1","title": "xxxxx"},
  {"id": "w2","title": "xxxxx"},
  {"id": "w3","title": "xxxxx"},
  {"id": "w4","title": "xxxxx"}
]
```

---

I get the feeling you're not understanding the structure of your JSON object, which is currently:

```
{
  widget: [
    {
      id: "w1",
      title: "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      id: "w2",
      title: "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      id: "w3",
      title: "xxxxx"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

You can sort of think of it as a 3-dimensional associative array (or 3 layers of associative arrays nested within one another):

```
/* in PHP code because JS doesn't have associative arrays */

$json = array( // first layer
  'widget' => array( // second layer
    0 => array( // third layer
      'id' => 'w1',
      'tit;e' => 'xxxxx'
    ),
    1 => array( // third layer
      'id' => 'w2',
      'tit;e' => 'xxxxx'
    ),
    2 => array( // third layer
      'id' => 'w3',
      'tit;e' => 'xxxxx'
    ),
    ...
  )
);
```

You're currently trying to loop through the first dimension of `$json`, which only has a single item. So the error you're getting is because you're trying to access:

```
$json[$key]['widget']['id'] // $key = 'widget'
```

when in fact you should be trying to access:

```
$json['widget'][$key]['id'] // $key = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

*Or* you can simply remove the first layer of your data structure and just access:

```
$json[$key]['id'] // $key = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

To avoid such problems in the future, make use of a JS console like Firebug's or node.js' or the built-in JS consoles that most modern browsers now have. Simply doing something like:

```
console.log(json);
```

or

```
foreach (key in json) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(json[key]);
}
```

would have revealed the problem.

Comment: tried this, but now the for loop wont loop, and i dont get any errors

Comment: @user759235: Do you know how to use a JS console for debugging? If so, put `console.log(json.widget[key]);` in the loop and see what it outputs. If you're doing either the first or second option, it _should_ loop.

Comment: lol, yes i know how to use the console.log ;-), i have tried it your way, but it didn't work, replaced the part that put's it in to the localstorage and now it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than forming the string in the loop why dont you simply create a object literal and then push data into it.

```
var store = [];
var i = 0;
$('.widget').each(function(){
 var obj = {};
 obj['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
 obj['title'] = $(this).children('h2').text();
 store.push(obj);
});
storeObj = {'widget':store};
localStorage.setItem('thelskey', storeObj);
```

Comment: well even if you accept my suggestion you will have to go with the solution of @lese-majeste at the end while looping....
So please understand the purpose and whoever answer feels better accept that answer, so people wont attend this question and save their precious time

Comment: This is an elegant refactoring of the storage portion. However, note that you should use `JSON.stringify(storeObj)`; otherwise, `localStorage.setItem()` will simply store `storeObj` as `storeObj.toString()`, which will probably just save `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: yes well i now know that the issue was in the setting part, so your code have helped me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var widget = [];
widget[0] = {"id":"w1", "title":"123"};
widget[1] = {"id":"w2", "title":"12322"};
widget[2] = {"id":"w3", "title":"12333"};
widget[3] = {"id":"w4", "title":"12344"};
widget[4] = {"id":"w5", "title":"12355"};

localStorage.setItem("db", JSON.stringify(widget));

var widget1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('db'));
```